# How to add new column to pandas DataFrame (from series) with some new indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

Lets say I have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0.5, 0.2],[0.5, 0.8]], columns=['Col1', 'Col2'], index=['Existing 1', 'Existing 2'])
new_col = pd.Series(data=[0.6, 0.4], index=['Existing 1', 'New 1'])
```

Which yields:

```
df:
            Col1  Col2
Existing 1   0.5   0.2
Existing 2   0.5   0.8

new_col:
Existing 1    0.6
New 1         0.4
```

What I would like to do is add new_col under a column called 'New', adding the "New 1" index, and filling empty with nan.  I have tried via:

```
df['New'] = new_col
```

However this does not seem to append the "New 1" index.  Thus I end up with:

```
            Col1  Col2  New
Existing 1   0.5   0.2  0.6
Existing 2   0.5   0.8  NaN
```

Where I want:

```
            Col1  Col2  New
Existing 1   0.5   0.2  0.6
Existing 2   0.5   0.8  NaN
New 1        NaN   NaN  0.4
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` to concatenate the series with the data frame along `axis=1`, which by default does an `outer` join, and thus inluding the index from both the data frame and Series in the result:

```
pd.concat([df, new_col.rename('New')], axis=1)

#          Col1 Col2    New
#Existing 1 0.5  0.2    0.6
#Existing 2 0.5  0.8    NaN
#     New 1 NaN  NaN    0.4
```

Comment: Excellent, this works well.  Is there any way to do this inplace, rather than having to do df = pd.concat([df, new_col.rename('New')], axis=1) ?

Comment: I don't think it can be done *inplace*, AFAIK. But you can avoid unnecessary data copy by specifying `copy=False`. `pd.concat([df, new_col.rename('New')], axis=1, copy=False)`.